# Force Jenkins to Pull from GIT on master

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

I have a Jenkins server running on windows as a service under a domain user account.

I can get Jenkins to pull my Git Repo (locally hosted Stash server) to the work space when run on the master.

I would like to execute the job on a Windows slave server. My problem is that when I kick off the project, the Master server sends the task to the slave first, and the slave attempts to do the GIT pull, but the slave does not have GIT or SSH installed.

I would like to avoid installing SSH and GIT on my slaves, I would like the master to do the pull first, and then push the work space to the slave and THEN have the slave start it's tasks.

Is this possible? Is there a plugin that will enable this?

Comment: I hit the same problem a while back and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: Why don;t you just stick the job to master, then archive workspace (or just tar it as an artifact) and then send it to a slave?

Comment: @Stanjer If I understand you right, are you suggesting two jobs? One to do the pull on the master, and then another on the slave that would  pick up the work space from the first?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I can't imagine other ways here. In fact it's a.common practice when you have a job that is creating your workspace and then sent it to different slave nodes for building, testing etc

Comment: @Stanjer The slave service runs as Local Machine, so I guess the first job would have to be the one to copy to some known location on the slave. So job 1's final build step would be to copy its work space to \\slave\jenkins\job2\workspace. I guess then job2's config would just reference $workspace. I just wish there a checkbox in the VCS settings that said "Restrict Pull task to Master" or something. This feels fiddly but I can see how it could work.

Comment: No, don't copy it in such way. First approach is cloning workspace plug-in. Another one is make a zip archive and archive as an artifact with Copy Artifact plug-in, then take that artifact as a build step. I don't like first time, because usually it's slower, but it has advantages, for example keeping all Env variables.

Comment: so, something similar is given below, but be aware - don't use copy files to specific folder - it's not a real CI. It will fail in 100 situations: 1) if you will change job name, if you will migrate to another server or will add new servers and so on and so on.

Comment: @Stanjer I agree that using a copy file to specific folder is a brittle strategy. If you want to write up your method using proper configuration with plugins I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I would like to advice you to have 2 jobs for that purposes. First job is bind to a master slave and the only thing it does is pulling source code from repository. Second job is fetching the code from first job and performing anything is needed for your workflow (compiling, running some pre-processors, running tests etc).

The question here is HOW to pass code between 2 jobs. I would like you to tell 2 solutions. Explicit copying to another workspace is a very bad practice (not clean workspace, changing nodes will fail it, changing name will fail it etc).

1. This solution is the easiest, but takes more time then another one. The main advantage here is preserving ENV variables in the slave step, so you will not need to define them one more time.
   It's based on https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin .
   At your first job, add a post-build step:
   [image]
   Then, at your slave job choose within the "Source code Management":
   [image]
   And you are done.
2. As in most of my cases I need speed for making everything faster, (1) approach is not always suitable for me. That's why I'm using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin .
   At my master job as the last build step I perform (assuming I'm using linux or I have bash tools installed for windows, if not then on Win you should use zip) some bash commands:
   `tar -hzcf dist/sourceCode.tar.gz ./* --exclude=dist --exclude=".git"`
   And then in post-build actions `Archive the artifacts`, defining that I want to archive `dist/sourceCode.tar.gz`
   In the slave job, as a build step I copy the artifact to the workspace:
   [image]
   And unzipping it:
   `tar zhxf ./dist/sourceCode.tar.gz -C ./`

The benefits are great - we are not bind to the names of the project, we don't need to think about where is the build running etc
As from my years of working with Jenkins (2) approach is the fastest one and the "cleanest" also.

Comment: This will work. I have a GIT web hook that can kick off the first job, and the trigger for the second will be completion of the first. That way I can have any number of jobs triggered by completion of job 1 that job 1 doesn't have to know about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem and the way I resolved it was creating two nodes and two jobs

```
Job1 -> Master
Job2 -> Slave
```

In `Job1` I am pulling data from GIT and creating a war file and then using `Copy To Slave` plugin which will copy data from master's `{Jenkins_Home}/userContent`  to slave workspace.

I have also used `Post Build Task` plugin to execute shell script which copies the deployment script along with the war to `{Jenkins_Home}/userContent`

## Master Job

[image: Git Repo]
[image: Build Task]
[image: Post Build Task]

## Slave Job

[image: Slave Build Task]
[image: Slave Post Build Task]